# Sumar Elementos y guardar en UseState

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

[image: Sumar Precios]estoy realizando un ecommerce y en la parte del carrito necesito recorrer "seleccion" sumar el valor de los precios y guardarlo en useState para despues consumir el resultado en el value del formulario pero no encuentro la manera correcta de hacerlo

Comment: El código debe ir _como texto, con formato_. Puedes darle formato entre triples acentos graves (```) o con el botón que indica `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

¿Puedes mostrar la información que recibes del fetch?

en caso de ser el siguiente formato:

```
[
 {
  'nombre':'name1'
  'valor':5
 },
 {
  'nombre':'name2'
  'valor':10
 }
]
```

Puedes recorrer el arreglo con la función map de JS y sumar valor con useState de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda que para sumar en JS debes asegurarte de que los números son de tipo numérico, de lo contrario podrías hacer una concatenación o algo peor.